# What is the difference between Docker plugin and Docker with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to jenkins. I want a way to integrate my jenkins and Docker. What is the difference between docker jenkins plugin and jenkins pipeline with docker?

I have read both this

https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=71434989#content/view/71434989

And this 
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

I feel like both approaches do the same thing running jenkins slaves /node on a docker container, but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I got this answer form Reddit post

> The first link is about using docker commands in your jenkins job to build your software. For example your tools are inside docker containers and you want to run `docker run --it maven:latest build` against your code. It is normally a single step in the build job.
>
> The second link is is about running a jenkins agent as a docker container and running tools inside the container against your code. Here you will run a jenkins agent, that will get the job definition from the jenkins master and the execute the jobs steps, i.e. more than one step also while being contained.